# Winston javascript logger is creating two separate log files. How do I log all entries into a single file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

I'm attempting to use [Winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) and [winston-daily-rotate-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-daily-rotate-file) to log all my console/log output from a node.js server to a single file that will (hopefully) get rotated daily at midnight.

The issue I'm encountering is that unhandled exceptions seem to generate a new log file rather than write to the existing one. See the example code below for the duplication behaviour. **How do I get all output to be saved to a single logfile as well as output to the console?** At present, the console side of things appears to be fine but feel free to point out anything obvious that I'm missing.

- OS: Win 10
- node: v12.16.0
- npm: v6.13.4
- winston: v3.2.1
- winston-daily-rotate-file: v4.4.2

```
    const winston = require('winston');
    const DailyRotateFile = require('winston-daily-rotate-file');
    const path = require('path');

    var logger = new (winston.createLogger)({
        transports: [
            new (winston.transports.Console)({
                format: winston.format.combine(
                    winston.format.timestamp(),
                    winston.format.colorize({ all: true }),
                    winston.format.printf((info) => {
                        const {
                            timestamp, level, message
                        } = info;
                        return `${timestamp} - ${level}: ${message}`;
                    }),
                ),
                handleExceptions: true
             }),
            new DailyRotateFile({
                name: 'file',
                datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH-mm-ss',
                handleExceptions: true,
                format: winston.format.combine(
                    winston.format.timestamp(),
                    winston.format.printf((info) => {
                        const {
                            timestamp, level, message
                        } = info;
                        return `${timestamp} - ${level}: ${message}`;
                    }),
                ),
                filename: path.join(__dirname, 'logs', '%DATE%.log')
            }),
        ]
    });

    logger.info("This is an info message");
    logger.error("This is an error message");
    setTimeout(() => {throw new Error('oh dear!')}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was caused by the datePattern option. winston-daily-rotate-file uses this pattern to determine the frequency of file rotation. As I had included seconds in the pattern it was looking for a file with the current timestamp (to the nearest second) and creating it before writing to file.

To get daily files I just needed to change

```
datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH-mm-ss'
```

to

```
datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
```